# Why is no callable?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Practicing with Solidity in version 0.5.0. I am Beginner.

I have seen that it is a common issue diving through the net but I have not found the reason, 
and the strangest thing is that I have seen people that the same code does not give the error and others do. Nothing has been clear to me.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Variables {

string public one = "One";
int public two = -2;
uint public tree = 3;
address public myaddress = msg.sender;

mapping(address => estructura) map;

struct estructura {
uint four;
uint five;
}

function setestructura(uint a, uint b) public {
map(myaddress).four = a;
map(myaddress).five = b;
}



}
```

The errors in the function are:
`Type is not callabe` and `TypeError: member "four" is missing or not visible after argument-dependent search in tuple ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fix it by replacing

```
map(myaddress).four = a;
map(myaddress).five = b;
```

to

```
map[myaddress].four = a;
map[myaddress].five = b;
```